# Getting html form output with JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Is there any way to get the parameterized URL generated during the submission of an HTML form with JS/jQuery, for the purpose of performing an ajax call?

i.e. I have a form with numerous checkboxes, and rather than use some jQuery to grab each value and prepare the URL, I want to try the approach mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the jQuery(form).serialize() as documented here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: That's precisely what I was needing. Thank you!